# Why does getting HTTP status: 500 error on running node js application on Plesk Obsidian

Tags: node.js, reactjs, plesk

Im getting this eror while running a simple react node js application on plesk

iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

```
HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1002
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
```

You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

The last 64k of the output generated by the node.exe process to stderr is shown below:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
C:\Inetpub\vhosts\abc.plesk.page\httpdocs\test1\src\index.js:1
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js:210:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
```